# How to forward calls in Android without extra application?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, oneplus-3

In Nokia, I did it by typing `*71003584012345678` where `71` for the unanswered calls, `00358` for the Finnish country code and the phonenumber `4012345678`. 
I know there are many applications for the task but I do not want to use them.

I heard that some Nokia Android phones and Sony phones have a builtin feature for the call forwarding in their phones. 
However, I cannot find such a feature in my Oneplus.

Phone: Oneplus 3T
OS: Android 7.1.1

Comment: I believe this isn't an original Android feature. Nokia has put it in its version, but other phones might not have it for you. So, you'd need an app...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Can it be supported by the carrier? What does happen if your phone is switched off? Is forwarding working then? I do not think so. - - Do you have any recommendations about the applications so I can test their effects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never tested (nor needed) this feature, so I can't recommend any app for that. Here, on Brazil, the carrier has this option for all kinds of phones - they charge for it, and it is not cheap at all, even for local calls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in Oneplus support chat

> In that case, please Go-to phone app-> click the 3 grey dot right top corner-> click settings -> call setting-> select SIM 1 or SIM 2.

Output: as expected. 
Details

- Set your Smartphone to Airplane mode or switch it off if you want to forwarding to go directly to your second phone. Setting: unreachable call.